# Getting Null Errors in infinite scroll with Realtime Firebase Database (Web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

So I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll for my realtime database. Currently, my code is loading all my images (stored as references) from my database all at once. Thus this is really slowing down the website, and is costing me more money due to all the data always being transferred. I have tried using a few lines to get a reference to the keys within the database in order to keep track of what data has been loaded:

```
//This snippet of code does not work
var referenceToOldestKey = '';
if (!referenceToOldestKey) {
firebase.database().ref('Posts/').orderByKey().endAt(referenceToOldestKey).limitToLast(10).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
    var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).sort().reverse();
    var results = arrayOfKeys.map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);
    referenceToOldestKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length-1];

    //loop thru and append content here to desired div
})
}
```

However I can not seem to get this function to work correctly. I keep getting a null reference where I call `var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).sort().reverse();` Where it will say 'Objects' is null. My current code (that loads all images at once) can be seen here:

```
/*READ PIC & DATA FROM REALTIME- PICTURES*/

var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/');
database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        var counter=0;

        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var url = data.val().url;
            var keyVal = data.val().keyVal;
            var dimensions = data.val().dimensions;
            var title = data.val().title;
            var year = data.val().year;
            var medium = data.val().medium;
            var additional = data.val().additional;

            content += '<div class="col-xl-4 col-xs-12 imageGrid" id="'+keyVal+'">';
            content += '<a class="lazy example-image-link" href="'+url+'" data-title="'+title+'&lt;br /&gt;'+medium+'&lt;br /&gt;'+dimensions+'&lt;br /&gt;'+year+'&lt;br /&gt;'+additional+'&lt;br /&gt;'+'" data-lightbox="example-1 '+counter+'"><img class="lazy example-image" width="300" height="200" src="'+url+'" alt="'+title+'"/></a>';
            content += '</br><button class="btn btn-danger deleteButton logged-inX" onclick="deleteFile(this)">x</button>';
            content += '<button class="btn btn-light editButton logged-inX" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalUpdate" onclick="getUpdateId(this)">&#9998;</button>';
            content += '</div>';
            counter++;

        });
        $('.displayImagesFromFirebase').append(content);
            setupUI(firebase.auth().currentUser);
    }

});
```

If anyone has any idea on how to incorporate these two so that I initially load 10 images, and then when my user scrolls to the bottom of the page, I will then load the next 10 images, that would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Upon speaking with Klaycon, I was able to get rid of the null error. However, now nothing is displaying at all, and there are no errors in the console. You will notice that I added `.child('Posts')` in my database reference line, this is the database I'm trying to reference. I also tested putting ('Posts') inside of ref() as well to no avail. New code is below:

```
var referenceToOldestKey = '';
if (!referenceToOldestKey) {
firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/').orderByKey().endAt(referenceToOldestKey).limitToLast(10).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
    if(snapshot.exists()){
    var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).sort().reverse();
    var results = arrayOfKeys.map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);
    referenceToOldestKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length-1];

    var content = '';
    var counter=0;

    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
        var url = data.val().url;
        var keyVal = data.val().keyVal;
        var dimensions = data.val().dimensions;
        var title = data.val().title;
        var year = data.val().year;
        var medium = data.val().medium;
        var additional = data.val().additional;

        content += '<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 imageGrid" id="'+keyVal+'">';
        content += '<a class="lazy example-image-link" href="'+url+'" data-title="'+title+'&lt;br /&gt;'+medium+'&lt;br /&gt;'+dimensions+'&lt;br /&gt;'+year+'&lt;br /&gt;'+additional+'&lt;br /&gt;'+'" data-lightbox="example-1 '+counter+'"><img class="lazy example-image" width="300" height="200" src="'+url+'" alt="'+title+'"/></a>';
        content += '</br><button class="btn btn-danger deleteButton logged-inX" onclick="deleteFile(this)">x</button>';
        content += '<button class="btn btn-light editButton logged-inX" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalUpdate" onclick="getUpdateId(this)">&#9998;</button>';
        content += '</div>';
        counter++;

    });
    $('.displayImagesFromFirebase').append(content);
        setupUI(firebase.auth().currentUser);

    }
    //loop thru and append content here to desired div
})
}
else{
    firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/').orderByKey().endAt(referenceToOldestKey).limitToLast(10).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
        if(snapshot.exists()){
        var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).sort().reverse().slice(1);
        var results = arrayOfKeys.map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);
        referenceToOldestKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length-1];

        var content = '';
        var counter=0;

        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var url = data.val().url;
            var keyVal = data.val().keyVal;
            var dimensions = data.val().dimensions;
            var title = data.val().title;
            var year = data.val().year;
            var medium = data.val().medium;
            var additional = data.val().additional;

            content += '<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 imageGrid" id="'+keyVal+'">';
            content += '<a class="lazy example-image-link" href="'+url+'" data-title="'+title+'&lt;br /&gt;'+medium+'&lt;br /&gt;'+dimensions+'&lt;br /&gt;'+year+'&lt;br /&gt;'+additional+'&lt;br /&gt;'+'" data-lightbox="example-1 '+counter+'"><img class="lazy example-image" width="300" height="200" src="'+url+'" alt="'+title+'"/></a>';
            content += '</br><button class="btn btn-danger deleteButton logged-inX" onclick="deleteFile(this)">x</button>';
            content += '<button class="btn btn-light editButton logged-inX" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalUpdate" onclick="getUpdateId(this)">&#9998;</button>';
            content += '</div>';
            counter++;

        });
        $('.displayImagesFromFirebase').append(content);
            setupUI(firebase.auth().currentUser);

        }

    })
}
```

Comment: where do you get null errors with your current attempt? that info would likely help people answer

Comment: @Klaycon Edited my question to include null location. Thanks

Comment: sorry, the wording of the error as you've written it is kinda unclear, there's no "Objects" and `Object` really shouldn't be null. could you paste the exact error text?

Comment: @Klaycon Sure, sorry for all of the confusion. Error -> 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.key' and it is the line number of the ```Object.keys```

Comment: I can see that you are missing a check if(snapshot.exists()){ ... } in the code that doesn't work. Will this resolve the error? I assume that snapshot.val() returns undefined.

Comment: yep, it sounds like you're getting a null result somewhere for `snapshot.val()` which is causing the code to throw. if it's throwing on only the first fetch, perhaps the issue lies in that `referenceToOldestKey` is undefined at the time that you use it in `endAt()`?

Comment: @ssBarBee Unfortunately no, where I have that comment saying loop thru and append content here, I basically took that snippet of code that does work, starting at the ```if(snapshot.exists()){...}``` and pasted it there, as  its job is to loop thru if it exists. I still get the error.

Comment: if you've put that snippet where the comment is, you'll be checking `if(snapshot.exists())` only *after* already trying to `Object.keys(...)` on it, which won't save you from the error. you need to wrap all of the other code in the exists() check too

Comment: @Klaycon Perhaps, but that is what I am most confused on. Unfortunately the docs for this kind of process are pretty thin, and that code comes from a tutorial website using React. Almost all of the other example posts here on stack are also using Angular, and mosty java.  So it has been difficult to really find a good plain JavaScript Web reference on how exactly these things are calling one another in that snippet.

Comment: well, the specific null reference error you have right now is very easy to fix - you just always check `if(snapshot.exists())` before trying to do anything to `snapshot.val()`, which you aren't right now. so fix that first, see what else goes wrong, and update the question with your results